# is there a way to read a sparse matrix in matlab even though the file is in dense format?

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I have a file with a matrix that includes the 0s (csv), and I would like to read it *straight* into a sparse matrix (lots of 0s) without having to convert the text file to remove all zeros.

Is that possible?

```
 sparse(load('file.txt'))
```

creates explicitly first a dense matrix through the load command, which is bad.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid it, since matlab require the file in memory before applying the `sparse` function.

Comment: You'd need to write your own reading procedure. Go reading the file chunk by chink (e.g. line by line), get the values, check wich ones are not zero, dump the rest, and go on. In the end you create a Sparse matrix with the remaining values.

Comment: While there is no way to load directly to a sparse matrix from a full one, if you have the ability to export your matrix in an alternative form, [`spconvert`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spconvert.html) does allow you to read a sparse matrix directly from a properly formatted file.